# Sending files daily to Amazon S3 using Spring Integration

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration outbound channel adaptor appending to a file. I want to append a date to this file (e.g. myfile_ddmmyyyy) and then setup a process which takes the previous days file and uploads it to an AWS S3 bucket and delete the local file.

Is that possible to do using Spring Integration and the Spring AWS extension  or would I need to use Spring Batch/custom process to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to file and even append you should use `FileWritingMessageHandler` with the `FileExistsMode.APPEND`.

To start some process after writing you can achieve via several tricks:

- `PublishSubscribeChannel` when that process is like a second subscriber
- `RecipientListSubscriber` when you have second channel for that process
- `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to attach to the `FileWritingMessageHandler` and initiate the process via its `successChannel` option.

To upload the local file into AWS S3 you should use `S3MessageHandler` as a (second) subscriber to that (second) channel. Injected `S3ProgressListener` can be used to delete the local file. Although you still can use mentioned above `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on the matter:

```
<int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter s3="s3" ...>
     <int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                <property name="onSuccessExpressionString" value="payload.delete()"/>
            </bean>
    </int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, I'll give this a go today :)